# Происхождение слова "городской"

Tags: этимология

**... предложил городской Думе подумать о его перестройке**

Укажите происхождение слова "городской".

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Городской - относящийся к городу.

Город - по Фасмеру, слово общеславянского происхождения, огороженное место. Для сравнения: укр. город, ст.-слав. градъ, болг. градът, сербохорв. град, словен. grad, чеш. hrad, польск. grod, в.-луж. hrod, н.-луж. grod, кашуб. gard, полаб. gord, лит. gardiny~s «хлев для мелкого скота», др.-инд. grhas «дом», алб. garth, -dhi «забор», гот. gards «дом», др.-исл. geri «огороженный участок земли», тохар. kerciye «дворец» (из ghordhiёom), фриг. Manegordum, Manezordum «город Манеса», греч. korq, cТrtoj, лат. hortus [1949].

То есть понятие «город» описывает некую совокупность селений, отдельных домов и др., которая огорожена «оградой», которой, в свою очередь, может являться и городьба, и вал, и русло реки, и стена и много другое, что отгораживает местность города от прочей местности.

Следовательно, городской - тоже слово общеславянского происхождения.